# NuGet does not copy dependencies with higher version than the one specified

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I have a Web project (**W**) which has a reference to a Class Library project (**C**):

```
W --> C
```

**C** references **N1**:

```
C --> N1
```

**N1** is a custom NuGet Package that has two dependencies (both are also custom NuGet packages): **N2** e **N3**, targeting version 2.1 or higher and 3.4 or higher, respectively.

```
N1 ---> N2 (>= 2.1)
   `--> N3 (>= 3.4)
```

When I added the **N1** package to **C**, **N2** had a 2.2 version available, so NuGet got that one, instead of 2.1, as it was expected to do.

The problem starts here: when I build **W**, **N2** is not copied to **W**'s `bin` folder. I googled a bit, and found out that Visual Studio does not copy dependencies that are not "first class dependencies", that is, dependencies which are not used directly by **C**, to **W**'s output folder. I can confirm that, because when I add the method below to any class in **C**, **N2** gets copied.

```cs
private void ForceCopyOfN2()
{
    var someObject = new N2.SomeClass();
}
```

Also, without the hack above, if I downgrade the version of **N2** to *the same* version that is specified by the **N1** package dependencies (i.e. from 2.2 to 2.1), **N2** also gets copied.

So I am guessing this is an issue with NuGet. Has anyone experienced anything like this?

Comment: Hi Alex,

This probably isn't NuGet, because its work ends after the packages have been installed in your class library project.

Which packages are these?

Thanks,
Clay

Comment: @ClayCompton, As I said, these are custom NuGet packages, which are hosted on a custom NuGet server. I have a hard time believing that NuGet just installs the package, because if **N2** the exact minimum version required by **N1**, then **N2** is copied to **W**'s output directory. Who else could be doing this copy?

Comment: I suspect this has to do with how msbuild resolves dependencies. Recompile with detailed build output turned on for each condition (N1v2.1) and (N1v2.2) and compare the build output results.

Comment: @JayWalker, Compiling with detailed build output definitely brought something up. The conclusion I came up with was this: When **C** compiles, it tries to find **N2** 2.1, because this is the version that **N1** requires. It cannot find it, but **N2** 2.2 is a direct reference of **C** (because of the NuGet dependency), so after a conflict it says "N2-2.2 was chosen because it was primary and N2-2.1 was not". When **W** compiles, however, it also tries to find **N2** 2.1 without success, but there is no **N2** 2.2 direct reference, so it does not copy anything. I am a little bit stuck here.

Answer (score -1):

I was not able to repro this with VS 2012 targeting 4.5, here is what I tried
1. Create new web application project 
2. Create new class library
3. Add reference from web application to the class library
4. in class library 
PM> install-package windowsAzure.servicebus
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager (≥ 1.7.0.0)'.
You are downloading Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=235167. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 1.7.0.3'.
You are downloading WindowsAzure.ServiceBus from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=218949. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'WindowsAzure.ServiceBus 1.8.0.0'.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 1.7.0.3' to ClassLibrary1.
Successfully added 'WindowsAzure.ServiceBus 1.8.0.0' to ClassLibrary1.

5. where service bus is dependent on configuration with >=1.7 and 1.8 version of configurationmanage is installed

6. build the classlibrary and then webapplication  solution, refresh the solution explorer. For my solution I saw  classlibrary, servicebus and configurationmanager are dropped in the bin folder. (not sure why but i saw the files dropped after I tried building classlibrary once again after adding the reference)

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: I follow the exact steps you mentioned, and neither _Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager_ nor _WindowsAzure.ServiceBus_ were copied to the WebApplication `bin` folder. Your NuGet output indicates you installed the packages to WebApplication instead of ClassLibrary ("Successfully added 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 1.8.0.0' to WebApplication15"). Can you try again and let me know?

Comment: yeah, you are correct, i missed out selecting which project to install from the package manage console. I think this is same as https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/586875/msbuild-4-0-incorrectly-processes-project-dependencies-specified-in-solution-file. Are you targeting 4.5?

Comment: I have updloaded my project where it seems to work here https://www.dropbox.com/s/3r3pgpwx8p5vwwq/WebApplication1.zip?m (I have to clean the bin folders and then build class library first and then webapplication. check on the disk or refresh solution explorer to see servicebus and configuration manager is dropped in webapplication bin folder). Can you share your project and I can give it a try.